Rotation vector does not update transform node

Rotation vector does not update transform node.
Without the rotate vector node the object rotates.
Don't know what I am doing wrong.

The purpose of the Rotate Vector node is to take a vector pointing in a certain direction and reorient it into another direction. Taking the vertex normal and rotating it by 90degrees on the X axis. The vector you're rotating is (0,0,0), so it essentially does nothing.

Thank you very much. The reorientation will be useful in the future.
